# ¿como construir un carrusel responsivo en html y css?

Tags: html, css

Estoy construyendo un sitio con un carrusel y he logrado que funcione casi todo, pero no logro hacer las imágenes responsivas a diferentes aberturas del navegador web, me explico, si se abre maximizado se ven las imágenes bien, pero no logro hacer que se vea solo la parte del carrusel, si se abre a un tamaño parcial, las imágenes no se adaptan al tamaño de la página y tampoco logro hacer que se vea solo la parte del carrusel.

Literalmente estoy atascado desde hace varios días, estoy empezando en la programación front-end y no se que mas puedo hacer.

Les dejo mi código e imágenes.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Rey</title>
</head>
<body>

<header class="main-header">

    <div class="header">
        <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>

    </div>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>

    <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img  src='img1.jpg' style='width: 100%;' alt="sally lightfoot crab"/>
            <div class="text">Sally Lightfoot Crab</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img  src='img2.jpg' style='width: 100%;' alt="fighting nazca boobies"/>
            <div class="text">A scuffle between two Nazca Boobies</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img  src='img3.jpg' style='width: 100%;' alt="otovalo waterfall"/>
            <div class="text">A waterfall discovered on a hike in Otovalo</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick='plusSlides(-1)'>&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div style='text-align: center;'>
        <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(1)'></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(2)'></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(3)'></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <center>
        <div class="bounce">
            <a href="#section2" >
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down" style="font-size:48px;color:blue"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </center>

</header>

</div>
<div class="main" id="section2">
</div>

<dl>
    <dt>empieza 1</dt>
<dd>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eius obcaecati asperiores sunt delectus, minima nostrum atque, officia dicta voluptatem rerum omnis beatae blanditiis debitis! Illo unde, placeat voluptas aliquam?</p>
<h1>termina</h1>
</dd>
    <dd>Apple</dd>
    <dd>Ant</dd>
    <dd>Altimeter</dd>
    <dd>Airplane</dd>
    <dt>B</dt>
    <dd>Bird</dd>
    <dd>Buzzard</dd>
    <dd>Bee</dd>
    <dd>Banana</dd>
    <dd>Beanstalk</dd>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Calculator</dd>
    <dd>Cane</dd>
    <dd>Camera</dd>
    <dd>Camel</dd>
    <dt>D</dt>
    <dd>Duck</dd>
    <dd>Dime</dd>
    <dd>Dipstick</dd>
    <dd>Drone</dd>
    <dt>E</dt>
    <dd>Egg</dd>
    <dd>Elephant</dd>
    <dd>Egret


<h1>empieza 1</h1><br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eius obcaecati asperiores sunt delectus, minima nostrum atque, officia dicta voluptatem rerum omnis beatae blanditiis debitis! Illo unde, placeat voluptas aliquam?</p>
<h1>termina</h1>

<h1>empieza 2</h1><br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eius obcaecati asperiores sunt delectus, minima nostrum atque, officia dicta voluptatem rerum omnis beatae blanditiis debitis! Illo unde, placeat voluptas aliquam?</p>
<h1>termina</h1>

<h1>empieza 3</h1><br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eius obcaecati asperiores sunt delectus, minima nostrum atque, officia dicta voluptatem rerum omnis beatae blanditiis debitis! Illo unde, placeat voluptas aliquam?</p>
<h1>termina</h1>


<h1>empieza 4</h1><br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eius obcaecati asperiores sunt delectus, minima nostrum atque, officia dicta voluptatem rerum omnis beatae blanditiis debitis! Illo unde, placeat voluptas aliquam?</p>
<h1>termina</h1>


<h1>empieza 5</h1><br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore eius obcaecati asperiores sunt delectus, minima nostrum atque, officia dicta voluptatem rerum omnis beatae blanditiis debitis! Illo unde, placeat voluptas aliquam?</p>
<h1>termina</h1>


</dd>
</dl>
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.slideshow-container {
        max-width: auto;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto
}

.mySlides {
    height: auto;
    /*height: 400px;*/
    border: solid 1px black;

}

.prev,
.next {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: -22px;
        padding: 16px;
        color: #222428;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        transition: .6s ease;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0
}

.next {
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px
}

.prev {
        left: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

.text {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #222428
}

.numbertext {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0
}

.dot {
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: background-color .6s ease
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
        background-color: #717171
}

img { border: 0; }

/*----------------------------------*/
.bounce {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50% ;
    width: 60px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: 60px ;
    margin-left:-30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -ms-border-radius:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    animation: bounce 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-25px);}
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-moz-transform: translateY(-25px);}
    60% {-moz-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}

@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-o-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-o-transform: translateY(-25px);}
    60% {-o-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {transform: translateY(-25px);}
    60% {transform: translateY(-15px);}
}

/*----------------------------------*/

dl {
    margin: 0;
}

dt {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px;
  position: sticky;
    z-index: 20;
  top: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
  left: 0;
}

/*----------------------------------*/
#myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10vh;
/*  justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 1140px;
  overflow: auto;
    align-items: center;
*/  z-index: 99;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
/*----------------------------------*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

**app.js**

```
var slideIndex = 1;

var myTimer;

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(1)}, 4000);
})



// NEXT AND PREVIOUS CONTROL
function plusSlides(n){
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    if (n < 0){
        showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);
    } else {
     showSlides(slideIndex += 1); 
    }
    if (n === -1){
        myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 2)}, 4000);
    } else {
        myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 4000);
    }
}

//Controls the current slide and resets interval if needed
function currentSlide(n){
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 4000);
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n){
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te acomoda usar librerías que ya realizan ese trabajo?

Comment: si claro, me puedes ayudar con algunas?

Comment: Echale un vistazo a [carousel de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) y a [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)